# Insert into a third table with many to many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables, one with stock IDs, one with user IDs, and a third with stock IDs, user IDs, and user by stock IDs.

Table 1:

```
 | stockID 
 | 10001
 | 10002 
 | 10003 
 | 10004
```

Table 2:

```
|userID 
| 11000
| 11001
| 11002
```

Table 3:

```
|stockID |userID  |userByStock 
| 10001  | 11000    0001
| 10002  | 11000    0002
| 10003  | 11000    0003
| 10004  | 11000    0004
| 10001  | 11001    0005
```

In table 3, I would like to insert into and have that all users have all stock IDs, and that the `userByStock` always increments by one.

So basically, I need to grab all stock IDs that don't already exist in Table 3 and add them to each user and increment the userByStock column by 1.

I've tried something like:

```
INSERT INTO table3 select table1.stockID FROM table1 WHERE table1.stockID NOT IN (SELECT stockID FROM table 3);
```

But I'm stuck

EDIT: I would also need to grab all userIDs from table2 that are not already in table3 and insert them into table3

Comment: use a cross join on the 2 tables to get all of the possible combinations then use an outer join to determine which records you need to insert.

Comment: Are you saying that you want full Cartesian product of the first two tables with consecutive unique numbers in an additional column?

Comment: @PM77-1 i think so, yes. and Matt, i could probably figure out the cross join, but then i have no idea how to get the outer join to work

Comment: Are you just increment the MAX(userByStock) which is what you are showing?  You just want an psuedo auto increment right?

Comment: @Matt correct, i just want to always take the max value + 1

Comment: Okay I haven't specifically tried my answer with your test data but you should be able to just grab the max, you can do it to a variable rather than a cte, or lots of other ways, then add that to a row_number window function in your select insert statement.

Comment: @Matt cool, i will try it myself. I don't quite get the where x.stockID IS NULL, because i need to check which ones already exist in the table3. or am i reading it wrong?

Comment: Is table3 empty? If it's not, what should happen with existing combinations?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. But isn't this as simple as this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9c102/1

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cteAllPossibleCombinations AS (

    SELECT
       StockId
       ,UserId
    FROM
       Table1
       CROSS JOIN Table2
)

, cteMaxUserByStock AS (
    SELECT MAX(CAST(userByStock AS INT)) AS MaxUserByStock
    FROM
       Table3
)

INSERT INTO Table3 (StockId, UserId)
SELECT StockId, UserId, userByStock = m.MaxUserByStock + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1)
FROM
    Table3 t
    LEFT JOIN cteAllPossibleCombinations x
    ON t.StockId = x.StockId
    AND t.UserId = x.UserId
    CROSS JOIN cteMaxUserByStock m
WHERE
    x.StockId IS NULL;
```

I guess the one note if you can I would modify table 3 and make it and actuall identity/auto increment column but if not just combine the max with a `row_number` and you should be good to go.  You can also use the same technique with the WHERE () IN SELECT answer.

Comment: thanks I forgot to add that when I saw Postgres I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a select for both the table a where on coupled value in not in

```
    INSERT INTO table3  select table1.stockID, table2.userID 
    FROM table1, table2 
    WHERE (table1.stockID, table2.userID) NOT IN (SELECT stockID, userID FROM table 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    create table table3 ( stockId smallint unsigned not null, userId smallint unsigned not null, userByStock smallint zerofill unsigned auto_increment primary key);

    insert into table3 (stockId, userId) select table1.stockId, table2.userId from table1 cross join table2;


    stockId | userId | userByStock |
    +---------+--------+-------------+
    |       1 |      1 |       00001 |
    |       2 |      1 |       00002 |
    |       1 |      2 |       00003 |
    |       2 |      2 |       00004 |
    |       1 |      3 |       00005 |
    |       2 |      3 |       00006 |
    +---------+--------+-------------+
```

But... If you can not add auto_increment...

```
   set @m:=(select max(userByStock) from table3); insert into table3 (stockId, userId, userByStock) select table1.stockId, table2.userId, (@m := @m + 1) from table1 cross join table2;
```

And... THE COMPLETE solution would be:

```
   set @m:=(select max(userByStock) from table3); insert into table3 (stockId, userId, userByStock) select table1.stockId, table2.userId, (@m := @m + 1) from table1 cross join table2 where not exists(select * from table3 as t3 where t3.stockId = table1.stockId and t3.userId = table2.userId);
```

Comment: i will try this as well, the thing is the incrementing has to find the highest value already existing in table3 and then always + 1 to that value

Comment: yes, but i can't make the column an auto increment column in table 3, i'm "not allowed" to manipulate that, i can only insert into or query from

Comment: This is not valid for Postgres

Answer (score 0):

I would consider simply doing an `INSERT IGNORE` assuming that you have a unique index across the stockID and userID fields on the join table.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table3 (stockID, userID)
SELECT table1.stockID, table2.userID
FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2
```

This would try to insert the Cartesian (cross) join of table1 and table2 into table 3, ignore all rows where the unique index of stockID and userID already exist.

Assuming that your userByStock field is an autoincrement field, thee values inserted into that field would automatically increment.

This may be a good solution when you think the number of rows you need to add to table3 represent a signficant percentage of the rows combinations from table1 and table2.  If you only have one or two rows to add to tables 3 and table3 has a signficant number of rows, this solution would probably not be as optimal as specifically identifying necessary inserts, as you would in essence be doing a bunch of inserts that are being ignored.

Comment: thanks, it's not an auto increment field, i have to increment it myself, which i'm stuck on

Comment: @mj95 Why not make it an autoincrement field? That is what they are intended to be used for - to give you a series of incrementing unique id's

Comment: i can't manipulate the entities of that table, only insert into it (it's a bureaucratic thing)

Comment: @MJ95 Well that is a shame.  Bureaucracies that force you to make (or not change) bad design decisions typically indicate a problematic software development environment. Simplification of the software system should always be the goal. As it stands now, you might need to either implement the logic with a stored procedure or a script.